# Database Structure Error

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table **Foods** having columns:

- Food_id(PK)
- FoodName
- FoodDescription
- FoodImage
- Category_id(FK)
- Res_id(FK)

And other table is **Restaurant** having columns:

- Res_id(PK)
- ResName
- Food_id(FK)
- Location
- email

When I try to insert record to any of table it gives error like:

> Getting “#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ”

Is the structure of table is correct?

Comment: You have a circular dependency. You need to get rid of it.

Comment: And please please please don't use irrelevant tags. MySql **is not** SQL Server.

Comment: How I can get rid of it?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to handle a many to many relationship. What you have is not the way to do it. As posted here you would have to have another row in Restaurant for every food they carry. And also an extra row for each food that is in more than 1 restaurant.

Comment: @SeanLange how I can correct it?

Comment: You can correct it by getting Food out of the Restaurant table, and Restaurant out of the Food table. Then you create a third table RestaurantFood that contains the primary key from both tables. This is known as an associative entity. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity

Comment: @SeanLange can we make two primary keys in a table?

Comment: No a table can have one and only one primary key. I think what you are asking is if a table's primary key can be more than 1 column. Yes this is perfectly valid and is called a composite primary key.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess (without knowing which database you are using) is that the two foreign keys are set to NOT NULL which means that a Foods record cannot be created without a Restaurant record to refer to, and a Restaurant record cannot be created without a Food record to refer to. Try making them optional, or even removing the foreign keys, then try to add records. If that works, you can reinstate the foreign keys afterwards by using an UPDATE TABLE command (check the reference guide for you database to see the syntax specifics).

Comment: This wouldn't fix the glaring normalization problem with the design posted. It would allow inserts to happen though.